# PhP -Passing Parameters in URL in Form

Tags: php, forms, url

My URL contains parameters for database Query but when i submit my form on that same page these Parameters are gone .hence resulting in an error for database queries.

**This is My URL**

```
localhost/forum_original_code/article_details.php?article_id=3
```

**This is the comment form i am trying to submit.**

```
`<h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
 <form class="well form-horizontal" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post"  id="contact_form">
 <div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="comment"></textarea>
                       </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

`

But when i get the posted values the Parameters form URL are gone.

**URL After form submission**

http://localhost/forum_original_code/article_details.php

Again resulting in data base query error. 
Can somebody guide me how to approach this better. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `POST` method in your form. If you `POST` something you will not be able to see those values in the url. You can access these values via the superglobal `$_POST['paramName']`. For additional information consider to take a look at the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php);

Answer (score 0):

Set action to

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);?>"
```

It will return complete URL with query string.

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` only gives you till localhost/forum_original_code/article_details.php